# Prove using mathematical induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n if_i = nf_{n+2} - f_{n+3} + 2\ for\ all\ n \geqq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This question is for the Fibonacci sequence, where $\mathit f $ is represented by the fibonacci function.

I have done my base step and elaborated my inductive hypothesis already, but I am having trouble with my inductive step.

$\pmb Inductive\ Hypothesis:$ Let z $\in$  $\mathbb Z^+$ be given. Assume $\sum_{i=1}^n if_i = nf_{n+2} - f_{n+3} + 2 $ is true for all n = z.

From what I believe, I must prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{z+1} if_i $ = $\ (z+1)f_{z+3} - f_{z+4} + 2$.

I have reached the following:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{z+1} if_i &= (\sum_{i=1}^z if_i) + (z+1)f_{z+1} \\
& = zf_{z+2} - f_{z+3} + 2 + (z+1)f_{z+1}\ \pmb(by\ inductive\ hypothesis)
\end{align}

I do not know where to take it from this point on.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to show it is true for $n=0$, then you should use $f_n+f_{n+1}=f_{n+2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for $n=1$, the equality is 
$$f_1=f_3-f_4+2$$

This is true because the first terms of the Fibonacci sequence are $f_1 = 1$, $f_2 = 1$, $f_3 = 2$, $f_4 = 3$.

Now, let's suppose that you have, for an integer $n \geq 1$, the relation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n if_i = nf_{n+2} - f_{n+3} + 2$$

Then you have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} if_i = (n+1)f_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^n if_i = (n+1)f_{n+1} + nf_{n+2} - f_{n+3} + 2$$

(the last step uses induction hypothesis). Using now that $f_{n+1} = f_{n+3} - f_{n+2}$, you get
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} if_i = nf_{n+3} - f_{n+2} + 2$$

and using $f_{n+2} = f_{n+4}- f_{n+3}$, you get 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} if_i = (n+1)f_{n+3} - f_{n+4} + 2$$

i.e. the equality at rank $n+1$. This concludes the induction.